# Any hints on how to graph this piece wise function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I am supposed to sketch the graph of

y= |x-1| if 0≤x≤2

|x-3| if 2≤x≤4
and specify any x or y intercepts

i'm just confused about graphing it because of the absolute value signs. Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is $$y=\begin{cases} -(x-1) & 0\le x\le 1\\ x-1 & 1\le x\le 2\\-(x-3) & 2\le x\le 3\\x-3 & 3\le x\le 4\end{cases}$$

Comment: why is it 0≤x≤11≤x≤22≤x≤33≤x≤4

Comment: instead of 0≤x≤2 and 2≤x≤4?

Comment: Because for $0\le x\le 1$, $x-1<0$ so $|x-1|=-(x-1)$, etc.

Comment: I tried graphing it and what I got looks like a "w"

Comment: is this right? and would the x and y intercepts just be the points on the graph?

Comment: That's right.  ~~~

Answer (score 0):

You can sketch the functions $x-1$ on $0\leq x\leq2$ nad $x-3$ on $2\leq x\leq4$, then you can get absolute from of your graph and obtain main graph.